# XNA 2D camera just part of screen

Tags: xna

Is it possible to use the 2D camera, but just for a part of the screen? Perhaps I want some info on the screen about score and other things, but I want that at a fixed place, just like when not using a 2D camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Since there's no concept of 2D camera built into XNA, I am guessing that you are using some class to generate a `ViewMatrix` and passing that matrix as a parameter to `SpriteBatch.Begin()`.

If that's the case, the solution is simple... All you have to do is draw your score and anything that you don't want to be affected by the camera in a separate `SpriteBatch.Begin() / SpriteBatch.End()` block, but *without* passing it the `ViewMatrix`. Example:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, null, null, null, null, camera.ViewMatrix);
// Draw game world
spriteBatch.End();

spriteBatch.Begin();
// Draw score and other information
spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Vector2 called Camera. Say you want to show an object with respect to the camera, i.e. a non-HUD object, draw it at a position given by:

DrawPosition = ObjectPosition - CameraPosition;

For the score and other HUD stuff, don't consider the camera vector.

DrawPosition = ObjectPosition;